# How to Execute the user defined python methods using variables, read from Excel sheet

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, xlrd

I have built my reusable framework libraries for **ClickLink**, **TypeInTextBox** etc and it sits in different python modules.

When I used the methods directly in the main class like `ClickLink('CP_SignIn_Link')` it works fine.

But when I tried to read it from excel and use the same like below I get the following error:

```
Keyword(wd_handle,Arguments)

print Keyword = ClickLink
print Arguments = 'CP_SignIn_Link'

Keyword(wd_handle,Arguments,Value)
```

`TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable`

```
Sample TC Excel Document:
======================

User_Keyword    | Keyword_Arguments         | Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClickLink       | 'CP_SignIn_Link'          |
TypeInTextBox   |'CP_EmailAddress_TextBox'  |'ABC@D.COM'    
TypeInTextBox   |'CP_Password_TextBox'      |'test'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the globals() keyword and it worked :)

Where User_Keyword variable will evaluate to a string equivalent to the method name in your package.

Example:

        `def ExecuteKeyword(driver, User_keyword, Argument)    # User_keyword = ClickLink , Argument = SignInLink
            function = globals()[User_Keyword]
            function(driver,Arguments)            # Equivalent to ClickLink(driver,SingnInLink)`

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: This will work ,because function is having an address here ,but try with function = 'globals()[User_Keyword]' this wont work.Check the type of the keyword  In your working  case and not working case. I belive, in the not working case it will be string type .

Answer (score 0):

I strongly belive that You are getting the  "Keyword" as a string ,
but you're trying to call it like a function. 
example :

> > > k =os.system
> > >       k('pwd')

/home/test/kelvin/pythonall
0

### But if we try  like this :

> > > k ='os.system'
> > >       k('pwd')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >       File "", line 1, in 
> > >       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Here ClickLink Is coming as string